# why double append of popup div

Tags: jquery

hi i have following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.card {
border:1px solid transparent;
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
height:136px;
margin:10px;
padding:3px;
width:136px;

}
.ui-corner-all {
-moz-border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--    <div id="popupContact"  style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;width:100px;height:50px;background-color:orange;border:1px solid red ;">
    </div> -->
<div class="card  ui-corner-all" id="card-208">   

    <div class="card-name">    Rahul1's Gib 1       </div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popup_pos=$('#card-208').offset();
    var timer;
    $("#card-208").mouseenter(function() {
        if($("#divtoshow").length==0){
           $("#card-208").append('<div id="divtoshow" style="display:block;background-color:green; border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;">'+
         'dsfdssd <a href="#">rahul</a>'+
         '</div>')
         }
            $("#divtoshow").css('position',"absolute");
            $("#divtoshow").css('top',popup_pos.top-120);
            $("#divtoshow").css('left',popup_pos.left-120);
            //~ $("#divtoshow").show();
     });    
    $("#divtoshow").live('mouseleave', function() {

            $(this).remove();

         });
});
</script>
```

Q why on mouseleave the divtoshow is not hiding it hide when i again mouseover it .

regards

rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by myself , i have seen the solutions of others they are good thanks to them for answering .

Answer (score 1):

You need some modificiations there:

- change 'mouseover' to 'mouseenter'
- use a `.live()` binding for `#divtoshow`
- access elements within event handlers via `this`

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/23/

Comment: it hide when i again take  mouseover it ,

Answer (score 0):

Either you can remove divtoshow on mouse leave event by

```
  $("#divtoshow").remove();
```

Or on mouse over event of popupContact div, first check existence of divtoshow, and if not exists then append it i.e.

```
      if($("#divtoshow").length==0){
           $("#popupContact").append('<div id="divtoshow" style="display:block;background-color:green; border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;">'+
 'dsfdssd <div><a href="#">rahul</a></div>'+
 '</div>')
      }
      // css statements will come here
```